# how to fetch data with useEffect?

Tags: reactjs, use-effect

I have an issue with fetching data and I don't what is the problem. Please take a look at the code below

```
import React from 'react'

const App = () => {

  const [avatar, setAvatar] = React.useState([]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
   
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => setAvatar(data.name))
      .catch((error) => console.error("Error fetching data: ", error));
  }, []);

  return <div> 

      {avatar.map(item => (
        <p> {item.name} </p>
      ))}

     </div>;
};

export default App;
```

Thank you!

Comment: the problem with linking codes is, the moment you delete the codesandbox link, this page becomes useless. Paste inline codes instead of posting link.

Comment: thanks that makes sense I didn't think about that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And now you forgot your import in your App.js file

```
import React from 'react';
```

And it also looks like the data you're fetching doesn't even provide links to images. If you only want the name, then you would use `data[0].name` or something like that, since the fetched data resolves to an array of objects.

Comment: thanks, but that didn't solve my problem :( I have pasted the code in original post as I was told not to share a link.

Comment: @Norby ok, now you are using `data.name` in your then callback, but it looks like you'd only want to use `data` here..

Comment: thanks, that solved my problem! I'm still new in react.

Answer (score 0):

The error is that you are missing a closed bracket after catch statement.

```
.catch(error => console.error("Error fetching data: ",error));
```